# PHP accessing array object

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I am using a third party software and the `print_r($_SESSION)` gives me this

```
[stsco-portal_current_user] => UserIdentity Object
    (
        [userName] => Gary
        [password] => 
        [persistent] => 
    )
```

I need to access the `userName` and have tried various combinations of the following

```
echo $_SESSION['stsco-portal_current_user']->$UserIdentity->['userName'];
```

keeps giving me an error.

I know i can access it(used it before in another project using a differnt system) i just forgot how to do it. Any help ?

Comment: `echo $_SESSION['stsco-portal_current_user']->userName;`

Answer (score 2):

There's no `$UserIdentity` variable. `UserIdentity` is just the class of the object, you don't need to specify that when accessing it. Just specify the property name.

```
echo $_SESSION['stsco-portal_current_user']->userName;
```